# Replace string cell references by cell content

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-poi

I would like to replace all excel Cell references in this string by their content:

`=WENN(DU18>=4;K5;WENN(DU18>=5;K5-10%;RUNDEN(1-(1-I18)*(1-J18)*(1-K18);1)))`

I would like to replace all the excelformulas by the cell content of their reference. However, I am struggeling to read the cell references.

I really appreciate your reply!

Comment: Why -1? Pls comment on your downvote!

Comment: How are you doing it now? What about your code isn't working?  Without seeing your code, it's hard to know what you are struggling with.

Comment: Please go back and reread [Ask] and the [FAQ] and compare those guidelines to what you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [FormulaEvaluator](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html) and call [evaluateInCell(Cell)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateInCell%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29) before you get the Cell value.

```
// Assuming you have a WorkBook workBook and a Cell cell.
FormulaEvaluator eval = workBook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
eval.evaluateInCell(cell); // <-- replaces cell value.
String value = cell.getStringCellValue();
```

Comment: How would you replace the reference in the text string by the cell value? I appreciate your answer!

Comment: I don't follow your new question, replace which reference in which text String?

Comment: It would be really kind of you if you could give a second example of the string replacement. (Thats the thing I am really interested in this question) Best regards!

Comment: @user2051347 Well, you could also do [`CellValue cv = eval.evaluate(cell);`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluate%28org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell%29), then you could call [`String value = cv.formatAsString();`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellValue.html#formatAsString%28%29)